# C++ fstream open

Tags: c++, io, fstream, filepath

I am able to create the files such as

```
f.open("file")
f.open("./path/file")
f.open("../path/file")
```

but not

```
f.open("~/path...)
f.open("/path...)
```

How do I get the absolute paths to work?

Comment: `~` is a interpreted by the shell. That is why that does not work

Comment: `f.open("~/path...)` resolving the `$HOME` directory is supported in the shell only. Not sure why your second case doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Sugihara, would you mind to accept one answer?

Answer (score 5):

By default, [`std::fstream::open(filename)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open)
opens `filename` for both input and output. Hence that file must exist and you must
have write permission to it.

In your cases:

```
f.open("file")
f.open("./path/file")
f.open("../path/file")
```

you were lucky.

In your case:

```
f.open("~/path...")
```

you used the path-element `~`, which means `$HOME` in the shell but just
means `~` in C++.

In the case:

```
f.open("/path...")
```

you were unlucky: either the file didn't exist or you didn't have write permission.

If you want to open a file simply for input then either:

- use [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)
- use `std::fstream f; f.open(filename,std::ios_base::in);`

If you want to open a file simply for output then either:

- use [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)
- use `std::fstream f; f.open(filename,std::ios_base::out);`

Answer (score 2):

With `f.open("~/path/....")` it is necessary for you to expand the `~` in code.  This is typically done by calling `getenv("HOME")` to retrieve the home directory, and replacing every occurence of `'~'` in the path with the home directory.

When working with absolute paths, like `"/path/whatever"`, you need to check that `f.open()` succeeds.   There are various reasons that `f.open()` might fail, including access control (protections that prevent opening a file), the file already being opened by another process, the directory does not exist, etc.

Notably, `f.open()`, when attempting to open a file within a directory, requires that all directories in the path already exist.   It won't exercise some magic to make them exist.   If you want that, you need to code it.  Bear in mind that each phase (creating directories, etc) might fail.